# How do I use pushd and popd commands in Terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

What are the practical uses of both pushd and popd when there is an advantage of using these two commands over cd and cd -?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very convenient if you're moving around the directory tree and essentially want to bookmark where you are so that you come back later. For example, if you're working on a project and want to go and look at something similar in a different file tree, then it's typically quicker to pushd , popd back to where you are.

Habitual command line users tend to get very good at a bunch of short cuts, which individually save seconds, but overall add up to a much improved "flow" of work. ! for example (to recall previous commands), !! recalls last command, alias for commonly used commands, h for history for example, etc. It's not unrelated to most of the older unix/linux commands being 2-3 letter acronyms - rather than the more verbose command line commands some of the older mainframe environments often had.

Comment: Seems like the `z` command might be an easier solution for switching to recently, frequently used directories? https://github.com/rupa/z

Answer (score 3):

The practical use is that you can build up a stack of directories, forming a trail of where you've been, simply by substituting `cd` with `pushd`.

You can then navigate to a particular directory in the stack with

```
cd $(dirs -l +N)
```

So, for example `cd $(dirs -l +2)` moves you to the directory #2 in the stack.

You can view the list of directories with their numeric positions with `dirs -v`

Most documentation will tell you to use `popd`, but that will also remove it from the stack, which may not be what you want.